# How to add CSS to mailto via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, mailto

I have this mailto script envoke via javascript. How can you add CSS?

```
window.open('mailto:user@example.com?body=test');
```

Comment: Hi, can you be a little more specific? Where and when do you want to add CSS?

Comment: You don't, that just tells the browser to open the system mail client.

Comment: Mailto links cannot produce an email with an HTML body (only plain text), so styling the body with CSS isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

mailto
launches the default mail application installed to compose an email.

Perhaps:
Link to a form that you style with CSS and use mailto on the submit, or other desired submit action.

What is your desired result or goal?